# trigger reloadGrid not refresh when close second browser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a problem calling the  `$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);`
after close event in another page.
I have one page with grid and i want to open second windows that not a child, when i close the second page event is fired but

```
<script>
        window.onunload = refreshParent;
        function refreshParent() {
          jQuery(window.opener.document.getElementById('#list')).trigger("reloadGrid");
        //or
           $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);          
       }
    </script>
```

refresh grid no reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If the event is firing properly remove the `, [{ current: true}]` and just call

```
$('#list').jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid")
```

If that isn't working, I would assume you have unique names for both the grid that would be opened in the child window and the parent?